# Serializer for class 'Any' is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

This is my code:

```
      override fun mergeItem(key: String, value: String): StorageResult<Nothing> {
        if (!ensureSetup()) {
            return StorageResult.Failure("Setup failed")
        }

        val changeManifest = atomic(false)

        val valueOld = getValueForKey(key)

        var newValue = value
        if (valueOld != null) {
            val mergedValue =
                Json.decodeFromString<MutableMap<String, Any>>(value)
            val entryValue =
                Json.decodeFromString<MutableMap<String, Any>>(valueOld.toString())
            if (mergeRecursive(mergedValue, entryValue)) {
                newValue = Json.encodeToString(mergedValue)
            }
        }
        writeEntry(key, newValue)
        if (changeManifest.value) {
            writeManifest()
        }
        return StorageResult.Success()
    }


 private fun mergeRecursive(
        destination: MutableMap<String, Any>,
        source: Map<String, Any>
    ): Boolean {
        var modified = false
        for ((key, value) in source) {
            val sourceValue = value
            val destinationValue = destination[key]
            if (sourceValue is Map<*, *>) {
                if (destinationValue is Map<*, *>) {
                    if (mergeRecursive(
                            destinationValue as MutableMap<String, Any>,
                            sourceValue as Map<String, Any>
                        )
                    ) {
                        destination[key] = destinationValue
                        modified = true
                    }
                } else {
                    destination[key] = sourceValue
                    modified = true
                }
            } else if (source != destinationValue) {
                destination[key] = sourceValue
                modified = true
            }
        }
        return modified
    }
```

Test case

```
    @Test
    fun testMergeAsyncStorage() {
        val map = HashMap<String, String>()
        map["key1"] = "value1";
        map["key2"] = "value2";
        map["key3"] = "value3";
        val jsonAbc = Json.encodeToString(map)
        AsyncStorage().setItem("jsonAbc", jsonAbc)
        val map1 = HashMap<String, String>()
        map1["key1"] = "value12";
        map1["key2"] = "value22";
        map1["key3"] = "value32";
        val jsonAbc1 = Json.encodeToString(map1)
        AsyncStorage().mergeItem("jsonAbc", jsonAbc1)
        val res =  AsyncStorage().getItem("jsonAbc")
        val map1Clone = res?.let { Json.decodeFromString<HashMap<String, String>>(it) }

        assert(map1["key1"] == map1Clone?.get("key1"))
    }
```

And is show this error:

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
On Kotlin/Native explicitly declared serializer should be used for interfaces and enums without @Serializable annotation
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
On Kotlin/Native explicitly declared serializer should be used for interfaces and enums without @Serializable annotation
    at kotlin.Throwable#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:24)
    at kotlin.Exception#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23)
    at kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34)
    at kotlin.IllegalArgumentException#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException#<init>(/opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/core/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/SerializationException.kt:48)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal#platformSpecificSerializerNotRegistered__at__kotlin.reflect.KClass<*>(/opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/core/nativeMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/internal/Platform.kt:22)
    at kotlinx.serialization#serializer__at__kotlinx.serialization.modules.SerializersModule(/opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/core/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/Serializers.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.serialization.builtinSerializer#internal(/opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/core/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/Serializers.kt:96)
    at kotlinx.serialization.serializerByKTypeImpl#internal(/opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/core/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/Serializers.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.serialization#serializer__at__kotlinx.serialization.modules.SerializersModule(/opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/core/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/Serializers.kt:59)
    at vn.momo.core.modules.storage.async.AsyncStorageModule#multiMerge(/Users/anhdevit/Desktop/momo-app-vix/shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/vn/momo/core/modules/storage/async/AsyncStorageModule.kt:385)
    at vn.momo.core.modules.storage.async.AsyncStorage#mergeItem(/Users/anhdevit/Desktop/momo-app-vix/shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/vn/momo/core/modules/storage/async/AsyncStorage.kt:23)
    at vn.momo.core.storage.async.iOSAsyncStorageTest#testMergeAsyncStorage(/Users/anhdevit/Desktop/momo-app-vix/shared/src/iosTest/kotlin/vn/momo/core/storage/async/iOSAsyncStorageTest.kt:115)
    at vn.momo.core.storage.async.$iOSAsyncStorageTest$test$0.$testMergeAsyncStorage$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$23.invoke#internal(/Users/anhdevit/Desktop/momo-app-vix/shared/src/iosTest/kotlin/vn/momo/core/storage/async/iOSAsyncStorageTest.kt:120)
    at vn.momo.core.storage.async.$iOSAsyncStorageTest$test$0.$testMergeAsyncStorage$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$23.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(/Users/anhdevit/Desktop/momo-app-vix/shared/src/iosTest/kotlin/vn/momo/core/storage/async/iOSAsyncStorageTest.kt:120)
    at kotlin.native.internal.test.BaseClassSuite.TestCase#run(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/TestSuite.kt:85)
    at kotlin.native.internal.test.TestRunner.run#internal(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/TestRunner.kt:245)
    at kotlin.native.internal.test.TestRunner.runIteration#internal(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/TestRunner.kt:271)
    at kotlin.native.internal.test.TestRunner#run(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/TestRunner.kt:286)
    at kotlin.native.internal.test#testLauncherEntryPoint(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/Launcher.kt:30)
    at kotlin.native.internal.test#main(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/Launcher.kt:34)
    at <global>.Konan_start(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/test/Launcher.kt:33)
    at <global>.Init_and_run_start(Unknown Source)
    at <global>.start_sim(Unknown Source)
    at <global>.0x0(Unknown Source)
```

Update:
StorageResult

```
sealed class StorageResult<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T? = null) : StorageResult<T>()
    data class Failure(val errorMessage: String?, val throwable: Throwable? = null) : StorageResult<Nothing>()
}
```

import

```
import co.touchlab.stately.freeze
import co.touchlab.stately.isolate.IsolateState
import kotlinx.atomicfu.atomic
import platform.Foundation.*
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import platform.darwin.NSUInteger
```

```
    private fun getValueForKey(key: String): String? {
        var value = asyncStorageHolder.access {
            it.manifest[key]
        }
        if (value == null) {
            value = getCache().objectForKey(key) as String?
            if (value == null) {
                val filePath = filePathForKey(key)
                val resultReadFile = readFile(filePath)

                value = when (resultReadFile) {
                    is StorageResult.Success -> {
                        resultReadFile.data
                    }
                    is StorageResult.Failure -> {
                        null
                    }
                }
                getCache().setObject(value, key, value?.length as NSUInteger)
            }
        }
        return value
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `mergeItem` is not represented, but even if it was - it's still not "minimal". You have the line in your stack trace - `AsyncStorageModule.kt:385`, you should place a breakpoint there to see what value are you passing. If this won't help you solving the problem, at least it'll help you reduce your example to minimal, as right now it looks like a mess.

Comment: It's much better, but things like `StorageResult`, `atomic` and `getValueForKey` are still not defined, so it's not reproducible

Comment: I provide some functions you need. Please check the lastest version

Comment: Make sure you understand the concept of [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `readFile`, `asyncStorageHolder`, as well as many other things are still not defined. Before asking me to check it out one more time, make sure I can copy your code into a newly created project and reproduce the crash. If I won't be able to run it one more time, I'm gonna ignore your requests.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?